# Ruby: Reusing code in instance and class methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a project using Rails and have a need to call a certain piece of code from both class and instance methods. I am doing the following now with redundant code in both the class/instance methods. Is there a better way to write this -

```
module OrderHelper

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def min_days_to_ship
    #to keep it simple, but has other code/logic
    3
  end

  module ClassMethods
      def self.min_days_to_ship
        #to keep it simple, but has other code/logic
        3
      end
  end
end


class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  include OrderHelper

  self.earliest_available
    Date.today + OrderHelper::ClassMethods.min_days_to_ship
  end


  delivery_after_date
    self.ordered_date + min_days_to_ship
  end

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instance and class methods `min_days_to_ship` are identical, just delete the `ClassMethods` module and add

```
extend OrderHelper
```

after

```
include OrderHelper.
```

See [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-extend).

If you want `min_days_to_ship` to be both an instance and class method whenever the module is `include`d, replace the module `ClassMethods` with

```
def self.included(klass)
  klass.extend self
end
```

which uses the hook [Module#included](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Module.html#method-i-included). In this case there is no need for `extend OrderHelper` in class `Order`.